# Iterate through all elements of XML file

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file like this:

```
<CustomerOrders>
  <Customers>
    <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
    <Orders>
      <OrderID>10643</OrderID>
      <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
      <OrderDate>1997-08-25</OrderDate>
    </Orders>
    <Orders>
      <OrderID>10692</OrderID>
      <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
      <OrderDate>1997-10-03</OrderDate>
    </Orders>
    <CompanyName>Alfreds Futterkiste</CompanyName>
  </Customers>
  <Customers>
    <CustomerID>ANATR</CustomerID>
    <Orders>
      <OrderID>10308</OrderID>
  <CustomerID>ANATR</CustomerID>
  <OrderDate>1996-09-18</OrderDate>
    </Orders>
    <CompanyName>Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados</CompanyName>
  </Customers>
</CustomerOrders>
```

and I want to extract each element to convert to lowercase. I understand that I can iterate through all of the nodes and childnodes recursively, but I'm struggling with outputting the actual elements.

In my code right now, I'm just printing all tags and their attributes, and also I can print out elements manually

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('customer.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for descendant in root.findall(".//*"):
    print descendant.tag, descendant.attrib
print root[0][1][0].text #prints 10643
```

What I want is to be able to print out each element of the file, and convert them all to lowercase.

Expected output:

```
CustomerID = alfki
OrderID = 10643
CustomerID = alfki
OrderDate = 1997-08025
OrderID = 10692         
CustomerID = alfki
OrderDate = 1997-10-03
CompanyName = alfreds futterkiste
```

And so on

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  "I'm struggling" does not describe the problem; please edit your post to include the actual output and what you expected.

Comment: have a try and feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt is as below-

```
import lxml.etree as et


s="""

<CustomerOrders>
  <Customers>
    <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
    <Orders>
      <OrderID>10643</OrderID>
      <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
      <OrderDate>1997-08-25</OrderDate>
    </Orders>
    <Orders>
      <OrderID>10692</OrderID>
      <CustomerID>ALFKI</CustomerID>
      <OrderDate>1997-10-03</OrderDate>
    </Orders>
    <CompanyName>Alfreds Futterkiste</CompanyName>
  </Customers>
  <Customers>
    <CustomerID>ANATR</CustomerID>
    <Orders>
      <OrderID>10308</OrderID>
  <CustomerID>ANATR</CustomerID>
  <OrderDate>1996-09-18</OrderDate>
    </Orders>
    <CompanyName>Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados</CompanyName>
  </Customers>
</CustomerOrders>

"""


tree = et.fromstring(s)

for txt in tree.xpath('//text()/parent::*[1]'):
   txt.text = "%s"%txt.text.lower()

print et.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True)
```

It prints-

```
<CustomerOrders>
  <Customers>
    <CustomerID>alfki</CustomerID>
    <Orders>
      <OrderID>10643</OrderID>
      <CustomerID>alfki</CustomerID>
      <OrderDate>1997-08-25</OrderDate>
    </Orders>
    <Orders>
      <OrderID>10692</OrderID>
      <CustomerID>alfki</CustomerID>
      <OrderDate>1997-10-03</OrderDate>
    </Orders>
    <CompanyName>alfreds futterkiste</CompanyName>
  </Customers>
  <Customers>
    <CustomerID>anatr</CustomerID>
    <Orders>
      <OrderID>10308</OrderID>
  <CustomerID>anatr</CustomerID>
  <OrderDate>1996-09-18</OrderDate>
    </Orders>
    <CompanyName>ana trujillo emparedados y helados</CompanyName>
  </Customers>
</CustomerOrders>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) using the `translate()` function. As information, XSLT is a special-purpose programming language to transform, style, re-format, and re-structure XML documents. You can avoid recursive looping across all nodes and texts in Python.

**XSLT** Script (save as .xsl or .xslt outside to be included in Python)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="lowercase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

 <!-- Identity Transform -->
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">       
     <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $uppercase, $lowercase)"/>       
 </xsl:template>      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python** Script

```
import lxml.etree as ET

dom = ET.parse('customer.xml'))
xslt = ET.parse('XSLTscript.xsl'))
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)
print(tree_out)

xmlfile = open(os.path.join(cd, 'Output.xml'),'wb')
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<CustomerOrders>
  <Customers>
    <CustomerID>alfki</CustomerID>
    <Orders>
      <OrderID>10643</OrderID>
      <CustomerID>alfki</CustomerID>
      <OrderDate>1997-08-25</OrderDate>
    </Orders>
    <Orders>
      <OrderID>10692</OrderID>
      <CustomerID>alfki</CustomerID>
      <OrderDate>1997-10-03</OrderDate>
    </Orders>
    <CompanyName>alfreds futterkiste</CompanyName>
  </Customers>
  <Customers>
    <CustomerID>anatr</CustomerID>
    <Orders>
      <OrderID>10308</OrderID>
      <CustomerID>anatr</CustomerID>
      <OrderDate>1996-09-18</OrderDate>
    </Orders>
    <CompanyName>ana trujillo emparedados y helados</CompanyName>
  </Customers>
</CustomerOrders>
```